# How to show a trapezium $ABCD$ with sides $AD$ and $CD$ parallel satisfies $AD+BC=AB+DC$?

Tags: geometry

I have been thinking about this problem for quite some time and unable to find any clue. I also have some troubles uploading an image here, but hopefully the question is clear enough.

How to show a trapezium $ABCD$ (can be drawn starting from $A$ in the top left in clockwise direction) where $AB$ and $CD$ are the pair of parallel lines and all its angle bisectors intersect at a point satisfies $AD+BC=AB+DC$? (where $AD$ means the length of side $AD$)

I am trying to use the property "sum of two sides in a triangle is greater than the third" and the "difference of two sides in a triangle is less than the third" but still unable to show the equality.

I really appreciate any helps! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Prove that the parallelogram is circumscribed to a circle (whose center is the point of intersection of bisectors...

Answer (score 0):

Prove that a circle can be drawn inside the parallelogram, touching all four sides.